# How to use electron methods inside svelte files - Svelte 3 - or is there any other way to do that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, svelte-3

I've been working on a Svelte 3 + Electron 12.0.5 project. I am using the [svelte-spa-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-spa-router) package for hash routing. My project structure looks like this:

```
node_modules/
public/
    build/
        bundle.css
        bundle.js
    index.html
src/
    Components/
        Pages/
            Home.svelte
            Settings.svelte
            ...
        Sidebar.svelte
        Titlebar.svelte
    App.js
    App.svelte
...
index.js // <-- Electron entry point
rollup|svelte|tailwind // <-- config files
```

Since I was using a router, electron's `window.loadFile()` was not working; To solve this, I used the [sirv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sirv-cli) along with [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). Now my start script looks like this:

```
"start": "concurrently \"sirv public --no-clear --port=40072\" \"electron .\""
```

Now I used `window.loadURL("https://localhost:40072")` to get this working. `.svelte` files, inside the `<script>` tags, I tried to do `import * as electron from "electron"`; but that resulted in a error saying `fs` is not defined. So for now, I created an express server inside `index.js` and am using using `fetch` to make `POST` request to the server and do the stuffs which I could've easily done using `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`...I don't know if I am doing anything wrong (nodeIntegration is already set to true). I'm kinda new to Svelte so do anyone know of any other way to use electron methods inside the script tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I finally solved my problem. I'm posting this as an answer so that others having the same problem can solve it. First of all, we don't need express anymore (you can also use it if you want). The start script is same i.e.

```
"start": "concurrently \"sirv public --no-clear --port=40072\" \"electron .\""
```

So instead of using `nodeIntegration`, we will be using `preload`. For e.g. lets consider a scenario of custom titlebar!

--- preload.js ---

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", { // "api" --> rename it to anything you want
         titlebar: action => {
             ipcRenderer.send("titlebar", action);
         }
    }
);
```

--- index.js ---

```
const { app, ipcMain } = require("electron");
...
ipcMain.on("titlebar", (event, arg) => {
    if(arg === "destroy") window.destroy();
    else if(arg === "kill") app.quit();
    else if(arg === "minimize") window.minimize();
    else if(arg === "resize") {
       if(window.isMaximized()) window.unmaximize();
       else window.maximize();
    }
})
```

And finally your svelte file; consider `Titlebar.svelte`

```
<button on:click={() => window.api.titlebar("destroy")}>Destroy</button>
<button on:click={() => window.api.titlebar("kill")}>Kill</button>
<button on:click={() => window.api.titlebar("minimize")}>Minimize</button>
<button on:click={() => window.api.titlebar("resize")}>Resize</button>
```

This was my use-case actually. I hope it helps! Advices are appreciated!